# Coroutine Scope inside repository class

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, repository, kotlin-coroutines

Lets assume that i have a list of Dtos, i want to loop throught them and set some values and then insert/update them to my Room database. So from my ViewModel i call the repository class, run the loop inside there and then i call dao.insertItems(list).

```
fun updateItems(itemList: List<ItemDto>) {
        val readDate = DateUtils.getCurrentDateUTCtoString()
        ???SCOPE???.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            for (item in itemList)
                item.readDate = readDate
            itemDao.updateItems(itemList)
        }
    }
```

The question is what kind of courtineScope do i have to use inside the Repository class. 
Do i have to create a repositoryScope with Dispatchers.Main..? Perhaps a GlobalScope..?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should write your repository APIs as `suspend` functions instead, like so

```
suspend fun updateItems(itemList: List<ItemDto>) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val readDate = DateUtils.getCurrentDateUTCtoString()
    for (item in itemList)
        item.readDate = readDate
    itemDao.updateItems(itemList)
}
```

Edit: if you need this to run even after the viewmodel is destroyed, launch it with `NonCancellable`,

```
suspend fun updateItems(itemList: List<ItemDto>) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO + NonCancellable) {
    val readDate = DateUtils.getCurrentDateUTCtoString()
    for (item in itemList)
        item.readDate = readDate
    itemDao.updateItems(itemList)
}
```

Comment: Hmm...ok. However i think thats a problem because if i call this from a ViewModel, and the ViewModel gets destroyed before this suspend function has finished, the above block will be get canceled. Am i right...?

Comment: Yes. If you need your function to continue running after the viewmodel is destroyed then use a scope that is not linked to the lifecycle of the viewmodel.

Comment: See updated response for coroutines that need to outlive the viewmodel.

Comment: This won't work if you're trying to hook stateflows up to a db

Answer (score 4):

Create your method inside repository as `suspend fun` and use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`

e.g.

```
suspend fun updateItems() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    //you work...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should default to using suspend functions in your repository that you can call from the view model using the `viewModelScope`.

```
class MyRepository(
  private val itemDao: ItemDao,
  private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
) {
  suspend fun updateItems(itemList: List<ItemDto>) {
    withContext(ioDispatcher) {
      val readDate = DateUtils.getCurrentDateUTCtoString()
      for (item in itemList) {
        item.readDate = readDate
        itemDao.updateItems(itemList)
      }
    }
  }
}

class MyViewModel(private val repository: MyRepository) : ViewModel() {
  fun updateItems() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
      repository.updateItems()
    }
  }
}
```

If you need an operation that shouldn't be cancelled by the viewmodel, then create a scope in the application and inject it into your repository.

```
class MyRepository(
  private val itemDao: ItemDao,
  private val externalScope: CoroutineScope,
  private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
) {
  suspend fun updateItems(itemList: List<ItemDto>) {
    withContext(ioDispatcher) {
      val readDate = DateUtils.getCurrentDateUTCtoString()
      externalScope.launch(externalScope.coroutineContext) {
        for (item in itemList) {
          item.readDate = readDate
          itemDao.updateItems(itemList)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class MyApplication : Application() {
  // No need to cancel this scope as it'll be torn down with the process
  val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + otherConfig)
}
```

Do not use NonCancellable unless you want to suspend cleanup code. Using NonCancellable is very risky as you lose control of the execution of the coroutine. It can lead to subtle and very hard to debug bugs.

If you're using Hilt, inject the scope like this: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/create-an-application-coroutinescope-using-hilt-dd444e721528